# How can I get the effect of indexonlyfirst for a single glossary?

Tags: glossaries, documentclass-writing, glossaries-extra

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{symb:c}{type=notation,name=$c$, description=the speed of light}
\newglossaryentry{symb:m}{name=$m$, description=mass}

\begin{document}
Referencing my glossary items: \gls{symb:c},  \gls{symb:m}.
\newpage
Referencing my glossary items again: \gls{symb:c},  \gls{symb:m}.

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

(and never mind things like acronyms.)

I want the "Notation" glossary to only show the *first* page on which a term was referenced; but I want the general glossary (or other glossaries) not to be affected. So, I can't just use `indexonlyfirst`  as a package option.

What do I do instead?

Comment: I believe you will increase your chances of a reply if you add an MWE to your question that people can use for testing possible solutions.

Comment: @schtandard: But I don't really have an MWE to show. It's not like I have a document that's broken. I'm asking about feature availability...

Comment: Sure, but none of us has a document where we could plug in that feature and see if it's working. If anyone wanted to answer your question they'd first have to construct such a document, which is work. If you provide one containing everything that is needed (e.g. two glossaries containing entries that allow you to see if `indexonlyfirst` is in effect) but nothing more (so it isn't confusing and unnecessarily long), that makes an answerer's job much easier.

Comment: @schtandard: I was assuming there may be some known mechanism for this. But I see your point.

Comment: @schtandard: Added an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the category attribute `indexonlyfirst` (not to be confused with the package option of the same name).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\glssetcategoryattribute{notation}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

\newglossaryentry{symb:c}{type=notation, category=notation, name=$c$, description=the speed of light}
\newglossaryentry{symb:m}{name=$m$, description=mass}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

Referencing my glossary items: \gls{symb:c}, \gls{symb:m}.

\newpage

Referencing my glossary items again: \gls{symb:c}, \gls{symb:m}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If you use a wrapper macro for defining the notation entries (or all of the other ones), you can set the category in the definition of that wrapper macro (the built-in wrappers like `\newabbreviation` already do that) and just have to set the category attribute for the correct category.

If you do define the entries for all of your glossaries directly with `\newglossaryentry`, you can set the category for all of them using `\glsforeachincategory` after the definitions. (This feels clumsy, but I could not find any more elegant way to do it.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\glssetcategoryattribute{notation}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

\newglossaryentry{symb:c}{type=notation, name=$c$, description=the speed of light}
\newglossaryentry{symb:m}{name=$m$, description=mass}

\makeatletter
  \glsforeachincategory[notation]{general}{\@temp@glsry}{\@temp@label}{%
    \glsxtrsetcategory{\@temp@label}{notation}%
  }
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

Referencing my glossary items: \gls{symb:c}, \gls{symb:m}.

\newpage

Referencing my glossary items again: \gls{symb:c}, \gls{symb:m}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. I don't quite understand your use of  `\glsforeachincategory`. Doesn't it require the items it iterates to already be in that category? 2. Is what you're saying essentially that I'm going to have disjoint sets of categories for different glossaries, so that I can "capture" glossaries using the set of categories encompassing their entries? And if that's the case - what if the glossaries are not disjoint?

Comment: 1. Yes, I iterate over all entries in the `notation` glossary that have the (default) category `general` and set their category to `notation`. 2. Yes. If the categories are not disjoint, this approach won't work. Defining a glossary style that only displays the first page (rather than only indexing the first page) may be the way to go then.